# How to get char from string as a variable name?

Tags: python, string, list, variables, char

I am newbie, just learning python and wandering how to get char that i get from for loop as variable name and not actual char

i have 3 arrays

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,3,4]
c=[3,4,5]
```

and for loop

```
for x in "abc":
    some_function(x)
```

for example this is my function...

```
def some_function(array):
    print(sum(array))
```

but it doesn't work... i want x to be 'a' but not as char, but as a variable a , array, that ill give to my function and do something

Comment: If you have a large number of such variables, you should really consider using a dict. See the duplicate for reasons why and good suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a string, use all the lists in a tuple like so:

```
for x in (a, b, c):
    some_function(x)
```

Now, `some_function` calculates sum of each list so the output looks like:

```
6
9
12
```

---

If you need to persist with using strings, create a dictionary to store the mappings and use it in your loop:

```
d = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4], 'c': [3,4,5]}

def some_function(array):
    print(sum(array))

for x in 'abc':
    some_function(d[x])

# 6
# 9
# 12
```

Comment: And tuples might be a tad more efficient?

Comment: thank you. of course this will work but i want to do it with string way... i am reading string from document, very long, i have unique arrays for each letter and i dont want to write if statement for each letter. isnt there way to do it without actually comparing and then sending through function with preassigned variables? need simpler way

Comment: @TrebledJ, yes, tuple iteration is faster than list (though not by big margin). Construction is the overhead. I should consider refactoring it. Thanks.

Comment: @CleverBot, as suggested in a comment to question, you should use a dictionary to store the mapping. See the link.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how it can be done.

Comment: yup dict actually worked, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it using the string `"abc"`, you can use the `eval` function:

```
for x in "abc":
    some_function(eval(x))
```

The normal 'proper' way to do it would be to loop through `(a, b, c)` like others have mentioned, but the nice thing about Python is that there are all sorts of fun ways to do things.

Comment: It's important to mention along that `eval` is dangerous and is less adviced.

Comment: Yes I agree, especially as a python newbie you shouldn't get into the habit of using it for such things. Though it is harmless in this specific case because it's clear that the only code that could possibly get evaluated is `a`, `b`, or `c`.

A similar but less dangerous approach: `some_function(globals()[x])`, assuming a, b, and c are global variables. `globals()` just returns a dictionary of the global variables. Change to `locals()` if a, b, and c are local variables in a function.